# NFC foreground dispatch fire both onCreate and onNewIntent

Tags: android, android-intent, nfc, android-pendingintent, intentfilter

I'm trying to make Activity A(the launcher activity) that can have the below functionality.

1. Start Activity A with nfc tag and read the nfc tag after the Activity A started.

2. Detect nfc tag when Activity A is on foreground.

It works at first like for a day. It will behave like

onPause -> onNewIntent -> onResume

After the app is left alone for an day or possible an hour, when I try go to Activity A and scan the nfc tag, it will behave like

onPause -> onNewIntent -> onResume -> onPause -> onCreate -> onResume.

Huge problems with the last 3 steps. I thought it should stop in the onResume after the onNewIntent??

No matter kill app, clear from android task list, also won't fix the problem until app uninstall and reinstall. It doesn't happen only on one particular device, it happens on most of my devices.

Would like to know how to fix this or if there is any work around. Thanks a lot.

Below is my code:

Activity A

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.adapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED);
    techLists = new String[][] {
            new String[] {
                    NfcF.class.getName()
            }
    };
    intentFiltersArray = new IntentFilter[] { intentFilter };
    this.pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, ((Object) this).getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    if (this.adapter != null) {
        this.adapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
    }
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    if (this.adapter != null) {
        this.adapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, this.pendingIntent, intentFiltersArray, this.techLists);
    }
    super.onResume();
}
```

Manifest

```
<activity
    android:name=".ActivityA"
    android:launchMode="singleTask">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
        android:resource="@xml/tech" />
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: is `onDestroy()` being called before `onCreate()`? If so, you are probably seeing a response to a configuration change. Android is killing the current `Activity` and then creating a new one to handle the config change. You can prevent this by adding `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` to the `<activity>` tag in the manifest.

Answer (score 1):

can you call this

```
super.onResume();
```

before

```
if (this.adapter != null) {
        this.adapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, this.pendingIntent, intentFiltersArray, this.techLists);
    }
```

and check again

Comment: Looks like it didn't happen again for now. Will continue observe the behavior. Thanks.

Comment: I have the exact same problem! Did this solution resolve it for you?